# HAML - what does the "!=" operator do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am looking at some seemlingly standard Haml code right now, but just noticed it starts off  with a "!=", and 5 minutes of googling has failed to give me the answer for what it does:

```
#What does the '!=' mean? 
!= cache_content_if_not_prefetched(params) do
  -if product_live?
    =render :partial => 'products/product_tile'
  -else
    =render :partial => 'products/unavailable_product_tile'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as using `=` but doesn't sanitize the HTML

See http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html

```
!= "Look  <up>!"
```

compiles to

```
Look <up>!
```

instead of

```
Look &ltg;up&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is used for [Unescaping html](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html)

Answer (score 0):

Read this [HAML Documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html). It will give you all the answers you require. I just searched for HAML tags.

Do a CTRL+F for !=. != basically valuates Ruby code just like the equals would